# passing variable to array list

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

My code looks like:

```
  $scope.filters = [{
    name: 'cat1',
    limit: 12 

}, {
    name: 'cat2',
    limit: 12
}];
```

Can I simply call

limit: varname or $scope.name

does it need to be in a specific format?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want to add an entry to the array? do you want to access the value of the properties?

Comment: I'd simply like to change the limit value via a variable rather than hard coded

Comment: $scope.filters[0].name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Array of Javascript Objects that looks like this

```
[ // array
  { // index 0
      name: 'cat1',
      limit: 12 
  }, 
  { // index 1
      name: 'cat2',
      limit: 12
  }
] // end array
```

That is assigned to `$scope.filters`. Now to access or set a specific objects contained in the array you must specify which element using the `array index` in square brackets.

```
console.log( $scope.filters[0] ); // {name: 'cat1', limit: 12}
```

Then you can use a property name to access the properties of one of the objects

```
var oldLimit = $scope.filters[0].limit; // = 12
$scope.filters[0].limit = oldLimit + 2; // = 14
```

So to recap ***$scope*** is an object, with the sub-element ***filters*** that is an array, that contains objects with the properties `name` and `limit`.

```
$scope.filters[index].propertyName
```

Comment: Glad it was useful! Thanks for selecting my answer!